# Is there a way to pass a variable inside a class to a function outside on php?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm coding a little "show more" button that retrieves an array from the server with ajax. It seem to be working with normal responses declared and set inside the function, but i can't retrieve data from a variable inside an existing class.

```
namespace Elementor;
class DB_Gallery extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public $dbg_more = array();

    protected function render() {

        //Some code here

        $this->dbg_more[] = array(some data)
    }
}

function db_gallery_loadmore() {
    $db_gallery = new DB_Gallery;
    $response = $db_gallery->dbg_more;
}
```

I expected that this would work, but out of the class it isn't. Inside it's all working like expected. The data that i'm trying to pass is an array of arrays. Everytime an element has to be inserted, i'm using this line of code to do that:

```
$dbg_more[] = array( 'id'=>$image['id'], 'url'=>$image['url'], 'type'=>$image['type'] );
```

Comment: How should this work? `$this` is a reference to the current object, in your case the `DB_Gallery` class. If you're not in that class then there is nothing to reference.

Comment: Sounds like you need to go work through a couple of tutorials that explain OOP basics.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to say that i tried in other ways, like `$db_gallery = new DB_Gallery;
      $response = $db_gallery->dbg_more;`

Comment: Within the normal constructs of the language, you can't access private members from outside of the class.

Comment: hi nico, can you confirm if $dbg_more is public or private?

Comment: public, sorry for the confusion i made. the response from the server is an empty array (as i declared in the public variable) not updated with what i'm doing in the render method

Comment: Does `\Elementor\Widget_Base` call the render function automatically? If not you obviously have to call it yourself. And since it's protected you either have to make the function public or if this is not an option create a public function that in itself calls the render function

Comment: Second what @LLJ97 said. For test you can initialise     public $dbg_more = ["Test"]; and check whether it returns empty arr or ["Test"]

Comment: \Elementor\Widget_Base call it for rendering the widget on the page, and that is working like expected. The class could be protected or public i still can't make this updated out of the method

Comment: Actually it returns an array with "Test" in it instead of an empty array. @LLJ97 I can't call it manually, it's called by Widget_Base and unfortunately, declared protected in that class. It seems to be updating only inside the class and then reset

Comment: @SaroshKhatana I was able to do that only with a session.. I think that's because when the class finish, reset all the variables... So, i can update a property value only outside a class, 'cause doing it inside doens't make changes visible outside of it. Same thing appening with global variables... Any idea on that? can i only do this with a session?